# OpenGL won't draw, why?

Tags: opengl, textures, draw, lwjgl

I'm kind of new to OpenGL, so I tried to draw a textured 2D rect. I don't know why, but this didn't work:

```
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glViewport(0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight);
    GL11.glOrtho(0, 640, 0, 480, 0, 128);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderer.getTexture("/textures/menu/title.png"));
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_ALPHA_TEST);
    GL11.glAlphaFunc(GL11.GL_GREATER, 0.1F);
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    GL11.glVertex3f(-frameWidth/2, -frameHeight/2, -1);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    GL11.glVertex3f(+frameWidth/2, -frameHeight/2, -1);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    GL11.glVertex3f(+frameWidth/2, +frameHeight/2, -1);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    GL11.glVertex3f(-frameWidth/2, +frameWidth/2, -1);
    GL11.glEnd();
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_CULL_FACE);
    GL11.glCullFace(GL11.GL_BACK);
```

frameWidth is the width of the window, frameHeight is the height.

Comment: You need to include more information in your question. Language, library, platform, etc. There are many things that could cause this.  First, ensure you have a valid context, and that it is active. Next, ensure your textures are correctly loaded and bound to the texture unit.  Try starting with some simple example code, such as drawing a coloured triangle, to ensure your setup is correct.  Then move on to your code above.

Comment: Well, if it didn't work, what did it do?

Answer (score 3):

Because you didn't actually write what went wrong, I can only guess, but here, you specified orthogonal projection with z in range (0,128).

```
 GL11.glOrtho(0, 640, 0, 480, 0, 128);
```

And then put your vertices with z = -1. Certainly it won't be drawn, as all the vertices will be clipped.

```
 GL11.glVertex3f(-frameWidth/2, -frameHeight/2, -1);
```

Try changing `glOrtho` to `gluOrtho2D` (or hard-coded equivalent), and all the vertices to `glVertex2f`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); glCullFace(GL_BACK)` before the rendering. If you are using `glOrtho` for 2D, you should be doing `glOrtho(..., ..., ..., ..., -1, 1);` and using glVertex2f for your 2D vertices.

Comment: How is actually face culling related to this question? How does actually face culling affect 2D rendering? It should be a comment, not an answer.